# Electric field on the surface of dielectric sphere and outside sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

Let a dielectric sphere of radius $r_0$ and permittivity $\epsilon_1$ is placed in medium of permittivity $\epsilon_2$. The electric field inside sphere is $\mathbf{E_1(\mathbf{r})} = E_0 \hat{z}$. What will be the electric field $\mathbf{E(\mathbf{r=r_0})}$ on the outside surface of sphere and electrical field $\mathbf{E_2(r)}$ in medium $2$.

I think electric field $\mathbf{E(\mathbf{r=r_0})}$ on outside surface can be found using boundary conditions of electric field

1. $\hat{r} \times [\mathbf{E_2(r=r_0)} - \mathbf{E_1(r=r_0)}] = 0$
2. $\hat{r} \cdot [\epsilon_2\mathbf{E_2(r=r_0)} - \epsilon_1\mathbf{E_1(r=r_0)}] = 0$

But how can I find electric field outside of sphere?

**My attempt:**
for electric field on the outside surface of medium

first write $\mathbf{E_1}$ as: $\mathbf{E_1} = E_0 (\cos\theta \hat{r} - \sin \theta \hat{\theta} )$ and $\mathbf{E_2} = E_r \hat{r} + E_\theta \hat{\theta} + E_\phi \hat{\phi}$

using equ.1:

$$\hat{\phi} [E_\theta(r=r_0) + E_0\sin\theta] - \hat{\theta}E_\phi(r=r_0) = 0$$
so
$$E_\phi(r=r_0) = 0 \qquad; \qquad E_\theta(r=r_0)=-E_0\sin\theta$$
using equ.2:

$$ E_r(r=r_0) = \epsilon_1/\epsilon_2 E_0\cos\theta$$
so on $r=r_0$ electric field is 
$$\mathbf{E(r=r_0)} = \epsilon_1/\epsilon_2 E_0 \cos\theta \hat{r} - E_0\sin\theta \hat{\theta} + 0 \hat{\phi}$$

Am I doing it right? How can I find field outside sphere in medium 2?

Comment: The outside of the sphere is a charge-free region, so Potential obeys Laplace equation. GIven boundary conditions, you can obtain a complete solution using a set of Legendre Polynomials

Comment: @Kutsit do you mean that I should first find potential inside the sphere and then assume potential outside of sphere and apply boundary conditions? By the way, is my first part of answer correct? one about electric field on the outside surface of sphere?

Comment: No, the electric field outside has nothing to do with electric field inside, you may refer to electromagnetism by DJ Griffiths, ch-2 or this :http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~minote/COURSES/ph631/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=emch3_.pdf